# What is a Primary/Foreign Key Field in this Database Model?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I'm looking at this database model and I'm confused about the "PF" in some of the tables. My understanding is that the PF is a "Primary/Foreign key" which could also be a composite key. I understand this situation for a many-to-many relationship, but what about situations such as the `Menu_Courses` table? The primary key would obviously be an auto-incremented column of type int, but what about the `menu_id` field? How would that be implemented in a database such as SQL Server?

The author also explains PF fields on this page: http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_db_schema/tutorial_slide_5.htm

[image: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/recipes/index.htm]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way I understand it is that these fields are primary keys on the table they are defined on, and at the same time they are foreign keys to other tables.

`menu_courses` has the reference to `suggested_menus` through `menu_id` and combined with `course_number` makes the primary key - that is each menu/course number combination is unique and uniquely identifies a row on the table.

You would normally implement this as a foreign key field on the `suggested_menus` table.

Comment: Yes, but additionally they are always part of a composite primary key and never stand alone.

Comment: So why not just make it a FK like in the Suggested_Menus table? Is there a reason such as it can't be null because it's a composite primary key?

Comment: @Robert - The point is that it **is** a composite key. You want to have multiple courses _per_ menu, but not same numbered course for any one menu.

Comment: Exactly. If you left it out as part of the primary key, the rest of the primary key would not be unique.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this just means that it is part of a composite primary key in the table, but a foreign key at the same time. In **menu_courses** the `menu_id` references the **suggested_menus** AND is part of the tables primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The PF indicates the the column is both a primary key and a foreign key.  As the primary key it is one of multiple columns that comprises the primary key.  That's where the composite key is referenced.

For example, in table `Recipe_Steps`, `recipe_id` is a foreign key to the `Recipe` table.  And, along with `Step_Number`, it comprises the primary key in the `Recipe` table.

Answer (score 0):

Portrayal here is misleading, when several `PF`'s are shown, they represent a single composite key.

If only one `PF` is shown, the `PK` of the table is used to make up the composite key, it seems to be the case in `Menu_Courses`.
It has its own `PK` and `PF` composite key consisting of the PK of the own table and the PK of the parent table.